# Allowing server to read files strait

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I use .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule phpMyAdmin/(.*)$ phpMyAdmin/$1 [L]
RewriteRule img/(.*)$ img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule css/(.*)$ css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule js/(.*)$ js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule robots.txt$ robots.txt$1 [L] ????
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Hot to allow to read robots.txt strait that it reads only robots.txt not urls like robots.txtasdfa, robots.txtttt, ....?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ - [L]
```